# What is stack traceback in python?

Tags: python

I am very new with Python, I do still not understand what stack traceback in python is?
Could you explain it for me?
Thanks for your help very much!

Comment: Try: `print(1/0)`  You will get a traceback...

Comment: It's the error message. It gives information on what went wrong in your program. It's called traceback because is detailed, if you read it carefully most of the times you can identify the error and fix it.

Comment: It shows the call stack at the time of the exception. That means what was calling what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack traceback displays the state of the *call stack* at a certain point in the running of a program. In practice, you'll usually encounter these when an error occurs in your program.

The [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) is a stack (or list) of stack frames. Each stack frame corresponds to the call of a subprocess (in Python, a function or [list]-comprehension). A stack is a data structure that can contain many elements, which are removed in last-in-first-out (LIFO) fashion.

This can be hard to understand in abstract, but with an example it's fairly simple.

Example:

If you have the program:

```py
def func1():
    func2()

def func2():
    print("func2")
```

And you call the function `func1`, the the call stack will initially contain a call frame for `func1`. Then `func1` calls `func2`, which adds a call frame to the stack. When `func2` exits, the corresponding call frame is removed from the stack, so now we're back in `func1`. When `func1` exits, its call frame is also removed and now the stack is empty again.

So we would have the following stack traces:

```
[empty] --> func1 --> func1 --> func1 --> [empty]
                      func2
```

Stack traces are useful in debugging, especially in more complex examples as they show where the program was when it encountered an error. For example, if we modify `func2` so that it looks like:

```py
def func2():
    1 / 0
```

We would get a `ZeroDivisionError` with the following stack traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in func1
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in func2
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

So we can see the error occurred in line 2 of `func2` (which was called on line 2 of `func1`).